# how to synchronously close a file in linux kernel cifsfs module, or in vfs modules in general

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vfs, cifs

I am trying to customize cifsfs module for my own use case, one of the case I need to open a file and read its content in the `cifs_unlink()` call, I am using `filp_open()` to open it, read it then `filp_close()` it, then continue with the normal code path of `unlink()`, I could get the content just fine.

Problem is, the `filp_close()` call will hold off the smb request until I am out of the `unlink()` function, so the unlink smb request will arrive earlier than the `close()`, and it triggers `0xc0000043 NT_STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION`, then the unlink will fail with `device busy`.
tried to call `cifs_close()` instead of the `filp_close()`, same result.

Wondering how I can synchronously `close()` a file to avoid this failure.